# How to call an override method manually?Overrided method is not running

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

I have deveolped a method to call methods from another calss.I have created an adapter and inside that I have an override getView(). What I need to do is to get values from a listview and display as a report. I have tried this exact code inside another activity in the same project. It works perfectly. But when ever I moved this into another activity it doesn't give any error.But the overrided method is not calling. What should I do to make it run?

```
public class ViewList extends ActionBarActivity {
    ArrayAdapter<Units> unitsAdapterView;

    ListView ViewAll;

    List<Units> Unit = new ArrayList<Units>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_list);
        ViewAll = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.viewList);
       populateListView();
        viewView();
    }
    private  void viewView(){
        Button m=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tryBtn);
        m.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //  startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewList.class));
                populateListView();
            }
        });
    }

    private  void populateListView(){
        unitsAdapterView =new UnitListAdaptorView();
        ViewAll.setAdapter(unitsAdapterView);
     //   unitsAdapterView.getView();
    }
    private  class UnitListAdaptorView extends  ArrayAdapter<Units> {
        public UnitListAdaptorView() {
            super   (ViewList.this, R.layout.list,Unit);
            Log.i("","A");
         //   A();

        }

@override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.i("","Resue connceted bulb 5");
            if (view == null) {
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list,parent ,false);

            }

            Units currentUnit = Unit.get(position);
            TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblViewName);
            name.setText(currentUnit.getName());

            TextView bulb=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblViewBulb);
            bulb.setText(currentUnit.getBulbNo());
            TextView fan=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblViewFan);
            fan.setText(currentUnit.getFanNo());

            return  view;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why this should not work. Have you done a clean build on your project?

Comment: Yah Exactly.The error was due to an error when calling my db class. That's why the error was thrown

Comment: Please either answer your own question or delete it so it doesn't end up in the "unanswered" list.

Comment: Ok I'll publish my own answer! Thanx though .. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after adding the codes to get all the existing data from database. After adding the below codes to the onCreate method the function is working now!

```
  DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    if (dbHandler.getUnitsCount() != 0)
        Unit.addAll(dbHandler.getAllUnit());
```